# Return only dataframe columns that satisfy where clause

Tags: python, pandas

Starting with an arbitrary dataframe, I would like to return a dataframe with only those columns which have more than one distinct value.

I have:

```
X = df.nunique()
```

like:

```
    Id               5
    MSSubClass       3
    MSZoning         1
    LotFrontage      5
    LotArea          5
    Street           1
    Alley            0
    LotShape         2
```

Then I converted this from a series to a dataframe:

```
X = X.to_frame(name = 'dcount')
```

Then I used a where clause to only return values > 1:

```
X.where(X[['dcount']]>1)
```

which looks like:

```
                   dcount
    Id                5.0
    MSSubClass        3.0
    MSZoning          NaN
    LotFrontage       5.0
    LotArea           5.0
    Street            NaN
    Alley             NaN
    LotShape          2.0
    ...
```

But I now want only those column_names (in the index of X) which don't have dcount = 'NaN', so that I can ultimately go back to my original dataframe df and define it as:

```
df=df[[list_of_columns]]
```

How should this be done?  I've tried a dozen ways and it's a PitA. I suspect there's a way to do it in 1 or 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Boolean indexing and avoid converting your counts series to a dataframe:

```
counts = df.nunique()
df = df[counts[counts > 1].index]
```

The key is to note the *index* of your `counts` series are the column labels. So you can filter the series and then extract the required indices via [`pd.Series.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.index.html).

Here's a demonstration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1], 'B': [1, 2, 3],
                   'C': [4, 5, 5], 'D': [0, 0, 0]})

counts = df.nunique()
df = df[counts[counts > 1].index]

print(df)

   B  C
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  5
```

Comment: Terrific. Thanks.  It seems I can completely skip 'counts' (although the step by step was helpful) and have `x[x.nunique()[x.nunique()>1].index]`

Comment: @ColinMac, I wouldn't advise this, because that means calculating `x.nunique()` (the really expensive part) twice.